# How to use map,filter etc with Observable in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, frontend

I have created this Observable:

```
const numbers$:Observable<any>=Observable.create((observer)=>{
      for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
      observer.next(i);
    })
```

Now when I am trying to use map or filter in this way

```
numbers$.pipe(map(x=>{x+110})).subscribe(x=>console.log(x)) //undefined
numbers$.map((x:any)=>{x*10}).subscribe(x=>console.log(x)) //undefined
```

It is giving as undefined. Any suggestion how can i use this?

Answer (score 2):

if you use `{` `}` you should use return

```
numbers$.pipe(map(x=>{
     return x+110
})).subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

You can also remove the `{` `}` and the `return`

```
numbers$.pipe(map(x=>x+110
)).subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

NOTE: If you want to return an object and not use return you need use extra `(` `)`

```
numbers$.pipe(map(x=>({number:x+110})
)).subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it.